# How to find number of times a function is called in R

Tags: r

In the "count" variable, I would like to get the number of times a function is called in R

```
FUN=function(x){

  spaces=Category=0
  k=50-nchar(levels(x))
  for (z in 1:length(levels(x)) )
  {
    spaces[z]=paste(replicate(k[z]," "), collapse="")
    Category[z]=paste(levels(x)[z],spaces[z],sep="")
  }
  df=as.data.frame.matrix(table(x,Sentiment))
  attach(df)
  tot=d+i+s;
  d_percent=d/tot
  i_percent=i/tot
  s_percent=s/tot
  HSI=(round(100+(i_percent-d_percent)*(1-s_percent)*100))
  Weightage=(round(tot*100/sum(d+i+s),1))
  HSI_Final=cbind(count,Category,HSI,Weightage)

  return(HSI_Final)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this

```
FUN <- local({count=1; function(x){
  HSI_Final=count
  count <<- count + 1
  return(HSI_Final)
}})

FUN(1)
# [1] 1
FUN(1)
# [1] 2
FUN(1)
# [1] 3
FUN(1)
# [1] 4
```

Here you create a local environment that holds the count variable that you can increment inside the function